# OpenGL How to use a invisible mask to hide objects behind it

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, depth, depth-buffer, stencils

I have an OpenGL problem to solve. I have an object/mesh A, an object/mesh B and a background texture C.

Initially the framebuffer is filled with background texture C. We draw both A & B in the framebuffer. We want to keep object A visible, and object B always invisible.

In the beginning, A is in front of B. During rotation, at a certain angle, B is in front of A based on the depth test result, but since B is always invisible, B's part should be filled with background C.

Does anyone know a simple approach to solve this issue?

Is stencil test a good approach? Basically set object B with a color, compare the color of B with background C, and show the background C when the test fail.

Does anyone have any sample code I can read?

Comment: just to clarify C is always the background - if B is rendered above A, you want C to be shown, and if A renders above B, you want to see A?

Comment: Yes, you are right. C is always the background.

Comment: ... so it's like B is a hole you render on A?

Comment: I think he just wants B+A to be the hole - if it's just B over C, then you should see B?

Comment: Oh, that's not how I read it. My answer isn't appropriate for that. Will edit if needed.

Comment: I don't understand the requirements, what happens if B does not overlap A? Do you want the background to be displayed instead of B only for the parts of B that are in front of A?

Comment: I want to make B always invisible, meaning B's part is always filled with Background C. But I want depth test to pass. If B is in front of A, don't show A, but show C. If A is in front of B, show A.

Comment: You want the depth test to pass _what_? As in, you want the depth values of A left in the depth buffer irrespective of the location of B? ... or you want the depth values from C wherever B was? So that you could actually see a hypothetical D, somewhere between A/B and C, through A where B was? While being allowed to draw D after drawing A/B?

Comment: @Howy maybe you should edit your question so it's a little clearer exactly what you want. "We draw both A & B on top of it" - means to me that A and B were both being rendering into the color buffer. If B is always invisible, then Tommy's answer should work.

Comment: Sorry, Tommy, Yeah. Your answer is correct. I tried and it works. Thanks MuertoExcobito, now I clarified the question. Please post your answer again. and I will vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to:

1. draw C;
2. draw B with the colour mask preventing writes to the frame buffer (but don't touch the depth mask, so that writes are still made to the depth buffer);
3. draw A, subject to the depth test.

The specific thing to use is `glColorMask` — if you supply `GL_FALSE` for each channel via that then subsequent geometry won't write any colour output. But assuming you haven't touched `glDepthMask` it'll still write depth output.

So, you've probably currently got the code:

```
drawBackground(C);
render(A);
render(B);
```

You'd just adapt that to:

```
drawBackground(C);
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
render(B);
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
render(A);
```

Comment: I'm going to withdraw this answer pending clarification on the question.

Comment: Undeleted by request.